# Prevent automatic proxy settings change in Windows

Tags: windows, browser

I have my office workstation where some script is running in the background and changes the proxy setting to some pre-defined value which I don't want to use. I have to check the proxy setting every time I open the browser and change it to the value I want. Is there any way I could prevent the automatic change by restricting permissions to some keys in the registry or something like that?

Comment: If your office policies allows changing proxy settings, than why don't you just turn of the script?

Comment: Actually, the problem is a lot of background applications and scripts are running and I have no idea which one changes the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the script runs under an administrator account, so you cannot prevent it from changing the proxy settings. What you could do:

- Write a script of your own, that changes the settings back
- Ask which script changes the proxy settings and turn it off

If your policies allow to change proxies, you should be allowed to turn the script off, if changing proxies is the only thing it does.